# Attempt to call missing method - Lua (Roblox studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to develop a game in Roblox and I have am cannot call a method on a class that I created. I have added my steps below. I am certain the path to the model is correct and I think I have created everything as I should.

I have created the following model

```
local PlayerLeagueUpdateModel = { }
PlayerLeagueUpdateModel.__index = PlayerLeagueUpdateModel

function PlayerLeagueUpdateModel.new(playerKey: StringValue)
    local self = setmetatable({ }, PlayerLeagueUpdateModel)
    self.PlayerKey = playerKey
    return self
end

function PlayerLeagueUpdateModel:GetPlayerKey()
    return self.PlayerKey
end

return PlayerLeagueUpdateModel
```

In a separate file I create a new instance of this model and I call GetPlayerKey(). Then print the result. It prints the expected value. I have provided the code below.
I then fire a bindable event.

```
local playerLeagueUpdateModel = PlayerLeagueUpdateModel.new(playerKey)
    
local playerKey = playerLeagueUpdateModel:GetPlayerKey()
print(playerKey)

PlayerBindableEvent:Fire(saveEventType, player, playerLeagueUpdateModel)
```

I have a script watching for this bindable event. The script is provided below

```
local function HandlePlayerActiveInLeagueUpdate(eventType: EventTypes, player: Player, playerLeagueUpdateModel: PlayerLeagueUpdateModel)
    local playerKey = playerLeagueUpdateModel:GetPlayerKey()
    print(playerKey)
    
    PlayerDataManager.UpdatePlayerLeagueData(player, playerLeagueUpdateModel)
end
```

When I call playerLeagueUpdateModel:GetPlayerKey() I get the following error message

> attempt to call missing method 'GetPlayerKey' of table

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

its supposed to be
local playerKey = playerLeagueUpdateModel.GetPlayerKey()

with a dot